# Git: How to prevent the local machine username from being posted?

Tags: git, private

I am using OSX.

I noticed that when I commit changes to my public project using my local machine using git, the user name on the commit (in the website - in the project page under "commits") is the username I use in my local machine and not my git username...

How can I change this? I wouldn't like to expose my local username to everyone!

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your username (and preferably email) in git configuration, using:
`git config --global user.name "your username"`
`git config --global user.email "email@domain"`